# how to install packages in python 3.3.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to Python and I have to use *Python 3.3.1* version instead of latest one...

```
pip install numpy
```

it returns

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried using the way i installed on *python 3.6* but seems to be not working here..

I don't know how to install packages like numpy, pandas, scipy, sci-kit learn, matplotlib etc... in the *Python 3.3.1*, could you please help..?

Do i need to install pip separately... ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/). Pip must be run in your shell, not in python itself.

Comment: I tried in CMD ->  python also ... but issue is still there..please let me know anything I missed out..

Answer (score 0):

**If you are in window try with:-**

Open CMD and

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

**If this is not working try with this**

just type it as your python programe and run it

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","numpy"])
```

Comment: Tried this.. got below error  {C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\0331\python.exe: No module named pip}

Comment: are you in same python path.Are you able to execute programe with same directory?

Comment: Run the shared code but got below errror

>>> import pip Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pip
ImportError: No module named 'pip'

Comment: i think your pip pointing wrong directory .You can try with uninstall python and then install it.Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

In my windows 10 machine, the pip.exe is in C:\Python36\Scripts folder. So I install required packages by either using command C:\Python36\Scripts\pip install package_name or first cd C:\Python36\Scripts and then pip install package_name. So far it worked me in different versions of pythons installed.

As suggested by ostue, please make sure that pip is installed with the python distribution.